# using array_sum() in a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm learning PHP. Having trouble understanding why this piece of code isn't working.

In particular: why is the result of array_sum($x) (1596) greater than $cap? Perhaps I'm not understanding the nature of while loops, but it seems to me (looking at a print_r($x)), the loop should cut out a step before it actually does.

```
<?php

function fibonacci_sum($cap = 1000){

list( $cur, $nxt, $seq ) = array( 0, 1, array() );

while ( array_sum($seq) < $cap ) {

 $seq[] = $cur;    
 $add = $cur + $nxt;  
 $cur = $nxt;   
 $nxt = $add;  
 }

return $seq;

}

$x = fibonacci_sum();
echo array_sum($x);

?>
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Best, 
matt

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way: if `array_sum($x)` were less than `$cap`, then the body of the while loop would be executed again.  Therefore, when the while loop has stopped executing, by definition the condition at the top of the `while` will be false. (*)  I think you want to say:

```
while ( array_sum($seq) + $cur < $cap ) {
```

That will stop just *before* you exceed `$cap`, which is what you seem to want to do.

(*) Yeah, yeah, disclaimer about the effect of `break` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Simple order of execution.

If you add a little variable watcher it's easy to see how this happens

```
  while ( array_sum( $seq ) < $cap )
  {
    echo $cur, ' : ', array_sum( $seq ), '<br>';
    $seq[] = $cur;
    $add = $cur + $nxt;
    $cur = $nxt;
    $nxt = $add;
  }
```

If you run this, the last output shows `610 : 986`.  So, 986 is less than 1000, which is why that iteration of the loop executes, but the very first line of the loop pushes `$cur` onto `$seq` anyway - completely oblivious to the fact that it just made the sum creater than the cap.  So when you do `array_sum()` outside the function, that 610 is part of it, hence the 1596.

So what you really want is when the array sum *plus the next value* is less than the cap.

```
while ( array_sum( $seq ) + $cur < $cap )
```

But, it's a bit weird that your function returns an array at all.  Why not just have it return the sum directly?

Comment: Thanks Peter, that makes perfect sense. Appreciate the clarity. And you're right, in the end the function should just return the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is less than `cap` the last time the body of the while loop is entered.  That's how while loops work in all major languages.  In this case, the sum is greater than `cap` when the loop is exited for the last time.